# laravel 8 fortify register view /register 404

Tags: php, laravel, fortify

i have problem with laravel 8 fortify. `My project on centos os 7 server`.
So first of all I install fortify.

```
composer require laravel/fortify
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Laravel\Fortify\FortifyServiceProvider"
```

then

```
php artisan migrate
```

So after  this command I change `config/app.php` file

```
App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
// App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
App\Providers\FortifyServiceProvider::class,
App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,
```

Then create in  `resources ->  views folder auth`.
in this folder i add new file register.blade.php

After this one in the `app ->providers -> FortifyServiceProvider.php`
add code

```
 public function boot()
    {
        Fortify::createUsersUsing(CreateNewUser::class);
        Fortify::updateUserProfileInformationUsing(UpdateUserProfileInformation::class);
        Fortify::updateUserPasswordsUsing(UpdateUserPassword::class);
        Fortify::resetUserPasswordsUsing(ResetUserPassword::class);

        Fortify::loginView(function () {
            return view('auth.login');
        });

        Fortify::registerView(function () {
            return view('auth.register');
        });
    }
```

In my main blade file code for nav  ` resources -> views ->  templates .

```
  <div class="d-flex">
                    @if (Route::has('login'))
                        <div>
                            @auth
                                <a href="{{ url('/home') }}">Home</a>
                            @else
                                <a href="{{ route('login') }}">Log in</a>

                                @if (Route::has('register'))
                                    <a href="{{ route('register') }}">Register</a>
                                @endif
                            @endauth
                        </div>
                    @endif
            </div>
```

Main (index) working fine, but the /login or /register not working.

```
Not Found
The requested URL /register was not found on this server.
```

Any ideas why not working? I try restart `sudo systemctl restart httpd.service`  , change code structure but nothing works.

updated,
Features

```
'features' => [
    Features::registration(),
    Features::resetPasswords(),
    // Features::emailVerification(),
    Features::updateProfileInformation(),
    Features::updatePasswords(),
    Features::twoFactorAuthentication([
        'confirmPassword' => true,
    ]),
],
```

Comment: On `/config/fortify.php` uncomment the line `Features::registration(),`

Comment: @Droid only one thing commented in this file is  ```// Features::emailVerification(),```

Comment: Do you have `Features::registration(),` line there?

Comment: @Droid yes, i have it

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  Having the same issue on Laravel 9

Comment: Same issue, can someone help here?